# Need to call jQuery (window).load(function ()) using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I need to call the `(window).load(function ())` using C#. Is there anyway that I could accomplish this.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean here. Can you clarify with a small example of what your trying to accomplish?

Comment: `asp.net` and `asp.net-mvc` are two very different beasts. What are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register whatever script you want with [`RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Define the name and type of the client scripts on the page.
    String csname1 = "PopupScript";
    Type cstype = this.GetType();

    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
    if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
    {
        StringBuilder cstext1 = new StringBuilder();
        cstext1.Append(@"$(document).ready(function() {
                                // Handler for .ready() called.
                              });");

        cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No! that is not possible. You can't use client objects in server-side script. For more info read - [Using JavaScript Along with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx)