# Calling jQuery function from C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have the function below which needs to be called from C#

```
$('.image-cropper').each(linkUp);
```

Can anyone explain how it could be done. I tried using the below code

```
    String csname1 = "PopupScript";
    Type cstype = this.GetType();
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    StringBuilder cstext2 = new StringBuilder();
    cstext2.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> $('.image-cropper').each(linkUp); </");
    cstext2.Append("script>");
    cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, csname1, cstext2.ToString(), false);
```

but it did not work.

Comment: @rick Schott It did not call the function

Comment: You probably need to wrap your JS in `$(document).ready()` so the DOM's loaded when you try to select elements

Comment: What browser are you using ? does it have a development console that can show you errors ? I ask, as it maybe that your emitted Javascript is executing before jQuery is added to the page.

Comment: Use the code I just gave you for document ready: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775284/need-to-call-jquery-window-loadfunction-using-c-sharp/7775311#7775311

Comment: This is a duplicate of many questions, but most recently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775284/need-to-call-jquery-window-loadfunction-using-c-sharp/7775311#7775311 as answered by rick schott

Comment: Why is your question tagged with `asp.net-mvc`? I sincerely hope you are not using anything like this in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: Its a duplicate of your "OWN" question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779548/calling-jquery-function-from-button-click-event-in-c-sharp?rq=1)   Please don't post same question again

Answer (score 0):

You should really be calling your code inside the jQuery ready function ie:

```
$(function() {
    $('.image-cropper').each(linkUp);
});
```

The likely reason your code wasn't working was that the image-cropper elements weren't in the DOM when your code was run.