# Calling jQuery function from Button Click event in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to load the cropped image into the asp:image without using Updatepanel. But the problem is it displays the image but it needs to load the $('.image-cropper').each(linkUp); function which is present in the jQuery(window).load() to start the cropping process. But using the RegisterClientScriptBlock method it would not fire that function. Note: $('.image-cropper').each(linkUp); should be initiated only after the image has been updated with new image. Can anyone let me know where the error is?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ImageResizer;
using System.Text;

public partial class Advanced : System.Web.UI.Page {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Button1); 
        if(!IsPostBack)
            Image1.ImageUrl = "fountain-small.jpg?width=300";
        if (Page.IsPostBack && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(img1.Value)) 
        ImageBuilder.Current.Build("~/"+ImageResizer.Util.PathUtils.RemoveQueryString(img1.Value), "~/cropped.jpg", new ResizeSettings(img1.Value));
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image1.ImageUrl = "cropped.jpg?width=300";

        UpdatePanel1.Update();
        string key = "executeCropScript";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), key, "<script      
type=\"text/javascript\">jQuery(window).load();</script>", false);


 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript? MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling jQuery function from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775491/calling-jquery-function-from-c-sharp) by same user

Answer (score 1):

use add attribute property of button.

e.g

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return:javascript functionname()");
```

Comment: I could use this attribute property, but I would like to fire this function after I update the panel using c#. If I use like this, then first the client script fires and then the c# code behind . I have used the __do update panel and it worked. But I was trying to find a way that I could do the function calling through the code behind itself

Answer (score 0):

you could try like this ...

```
     <html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>  
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){    
    $("button:first").click(function () {
      update($("span:first"));
    });
    $("button:last").click(function () {
      $("button:first").trigger('click');

      update($("span:last"));
    });

    function update(j) {
      var n = parseInt(j.text(), 10);
      j.text(n + 1);
    }
  });
  </script>
  <style>
  button { margin:10px; }
  div { color:blue; font-weight:bold; }
  span { color:red; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Button #1</button>
  <button>Button #2</button>
  <div><span>0</span> button #1 clicks.</div>
  <div><span>0</span> button #2 clicks.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are plenty of topics on this on StackOverflow, just search for 'jQuery Code behind'